# Solving inequality with logarithmic expression

Tags: inequalities

I am trying to solve the following inequality

```
2 y(Log[1 + (y-1)x] - x Log[y]) - x(1 - x)(y - 1)^2 < 0
```

where

```
y > 1 && x < 1/2 && x > 0.
```

`RegionPlot` can handle my description but any other command (`Reduce`, `Solve`) can not. I would like Mathematica to help me extract an explicit relation between $x$ and $y$. Any help?

Comment: Can you post the Mathematica code you tried?

Comment: I strongly doubt that there is a closed-form solution to this equation for $x$ or $y$ in terms of elementary functions.  In general, equations that can be solved for one variable or the other are the exception, not the rule.

Comment: If I plot RegionPlot[2 y(Log[1 + (y-1)x]- x Log[y])- x(1-x)(y-1)^2<0, {x, 0, 0.5}, {y, 1, 1000}], graph suggests that for all x there exists a threshold y(x) above which the inequality is satisfied. I would like to extrapolate the threshold y(x), as I can't do it analytically. Impossible? Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extending answer by `user64494`

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)

(data = Table[{y, 
     Reduce[2*y*(Log[1 + (y - 1)*x] - x*Log[y]) - x*(1 - x)*(y - 1)^2 < 0 && 
       x >= 0 && x <= 1/2 && y > 1, x, Reals]}, {y, 11/10, 3, 1/10}]) // 
 Short[#, 3] &
```

[image]

The upper bound on `x` is `1/2` and the lower bound is a function of `y`. Use [`Interpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) to approximate the lower bound for a specified range of `y`.

```
xLowerBound = Interpolation[{#[[1]], #[[2, 1]]} & /@ data];
```

Plotting the range on `x` as a function of `y`

```
Plot[{1/2, xLowerBound[y]}, {y, 11/10, 3},
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {y, xRange}),
 PlotLegends ->
  Placed[{"upper bound", "lower bound"}, {0.25, 0.25}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am working on your reply.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this is what I was looking for. I am not familiar with the interpolation command (and rather new to Mathematica in general), and even after checking the manual I do not fully understand what is inside the square brackets {#[[1]], #[[2, 1]]} & /@ data]. Thanks again

Comment: `data` elements have form `{y, lowerbound < x <= upperbound}`.
`{#[[1]], #[[2, 1]]} &` is  pure [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) that extracts (using [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)([[...]])) pair `{y, lowerbound}` from a data element. Pure function is mapped ([`/@`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html)) onto `data` to generate `{y, lowerbound}` pairs. `{y, lowerbound}` pairs are input to [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html) to produce `xLowerBound` pure function.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an explanation. Up to the documentation to `Reduce`, the command solves transcendental inequalities, solvable using inverse functions. When trying

```
ClearAll[x, y];y = 2;Reduce[2 *y*(Log[1 + (y - 1)*x] - x* Log[y])- x*(1 - x)*(y - 1)^2 < 0&& 
  x >= 0 && x <= 1/2 && y > 1, x, Reals]
```

, the code is running for several minutes, resulting in

> Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.

and

> Root[{4 Log[1 + #] - # - 4 Log[2] # + #^2& , 
>      0.37252233714804266228535622730788445063`20.363517360744417}] < x 
>   <= 1/2

This means Mathematica is not able to solve the above inequality, making use of inverse functions, so Mathematica solves it numerically. Every soft has its limitations. Perhaps, this is impossible at all.

PS. A similar example is given in the "Exp-log equation" section.

Comment: thank you for your time

Answer (score 4):

Since you can not get an analytical solution y[x], generate an interpolating function ysol[x] solving the differentiated equation with NDSolve. Get initial value with FindRoot.

```
g[x_, y_] = 2*y*(Log[1 + (y - 1)*x] - x*Log[y]) - x*(1 - x)*(y - 1)^2;

dgl = D[g[x, y[x]] == 0, x] // FullSimplify;

yfr = y /. First@FindRoot[g[1/3, y] == 0, {y, 5}]

ysol = y /. First@NDSolve[{dgl, y[1/3] == yfr}, y, {x, 10^-6, 1/2}]

p1 = RegionPlot[y > ysol[x], {x, 0, 1/2}, {y, 1, 200}, 
        PlotPoints -> 50]
```

Comment: +1. It's an unexpected approach. Can you kindly comment your code? A good code is a commented code. TIA.

Comment: Regard y as a function of x,  y -> y[x]. When differentiating an equation, you get derivative terms, but equation is still valid. You can solve the found differential equation with initial value found from equation.

Comment: This approach produces an incorrect result when slices consist of several intervals.

Comment: You can of course adapt it to that cases. This here is an answer to this question here.